# how to use protected methods of two classes c#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface

Is it possible to use protected methods of the multiple classes? (I used the interface, but it only works with public methods)

```
    class A { protected void MessageA() { Console.WriteLine("hiii I'm A"); } }

    class B { protected void MessageB() { Console.WriteLine("hiii I'm B"); } }

    class C :A { 
        public void MessageC() {
            Console.WriteLine("hiii I'm C");
        }
        public void MessageA() {
            MessageC();
            base.MessageA();
        }
        public void MessageB() {
            MessageC();
            //what shoud I do here?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well you can't derive from both A and B within the same class, so no. This is a bit of an XY problem though - we don't know what you're actually trying to achieve, only that you're trying to do it with protected methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet 
i'm newbie in c#.I was curious to know about this. Is this problem not encountered in projects?

Comment: No, because protected methods are designed to be accessed by derived classes. If a method should be available to unrelated classes, it should be public. Again, we can't really tell why you think it *would* be a problem.